# Add argc for Windows cmd

Tags: c++, linux, windows, argc

Using Linux, when running a C++ program that takes a .txt file as an argc. i.e.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

I can simply compile it, then type `./a.out file.txt`

When using windows, after compiling it, how do i then run it including the file.txt as the argc?

Comment: `a.exe file.txt` should do the trick, assuming you're running the program from the command line (since it is a command-line program, after all).  Or you could drag and drop `file.txt` onto `a.exe`.

Comment: @ImraazRally: the question very clearly asks for `file.txt` to be an argument, *not* redirected to standard input.

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it this same way, only the name of the executable changes e.g., `program_name.exe file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you would normally use `./a.out file.txt` (the default in Linux is that the current directory is not searched for executables). In Windows' standard command interpreter you can just write `a file.txt`, assuming that you have named your program `a.exe` (Windows' command interpreter searches the current directory regardless of your `PATH`). Different compilers differ in how you name the executable file, but with g++ use `-o a` and with Visual C++ use `/Fea`.

One way to run the Windows command interpreter is <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `cmd` in the Run-dialog that pops up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run "cmd"
2. Change directory to the executable file exists with command "cd"
3. Exactly do that you did in Linux.